# Image loading slow on github pages website

Tags: javascript, html, image, github, github-pages

I have a simple website created with `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript` and it's hosted on Github pages. But on my site I have like 20 images and when I open my site on the browser it takes a while for the images to load.

How can I make my images load immediately or just faster? Is it because of Github pages host or is it because there are a lot of images on one site?

I have seen websites with more images than that and they are like preloaded or something.

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B3MY.png)

Comment: Can you link your github pages? It could be that some of the images are simply large but you can run a performance test on [google's lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) to check what's slowing the site down.

Comment: Without seeing the images you might need to resize them or optimize them for the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ways to make images load faster on page

### 0. Check what's slowing down your page

You can try finding what's slowing it down here: https://web.dev/measure/

### 1. Compress your image

You might need to compress your image if you don't need it to have so much quality. If you need quality, go to option 2. One website that does this is [Kraken](https://kraken.io/web-interface). This should allow the page to load faster.

### 2. Use a CDN

If it still does not work, use a CDN, or content delivery network, to host your images. CDN's store data in many data centers, making it to load data quicker. Try hosting your images in [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com).

### 3. Make your images smaller

Large images can make your site load slower. So, resize them so they are a bit smaller.

##### I hope this helps you!

Comment: The article linked is specific to Wordpress, which isn’t in scope for this question.

Comment: Oops - wrong article.